# Solution of a system of ODE with Dsolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

I am trying to solve following ODE with Dsolve.

```
a1[t_] = 2 - 3*Exp[-2*t];
a2[t_] = 1 + Exp[-3*t];
a3[t_] = 4 + Exp[-5*t]
```

$B=\begin{bmatrix}a1[t] & a2[t] & 0\\a2[t] & a1[t] - a2[t] & 0\\ a3[t] & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

```
  X[t_] = {x[t], y[t], z[t]}
system = X'[t] == B.X[t]
```

which gives

```
{x'[t],y'[t],z'[t]} == {(2 - 3 E^(-2 t)) x[t] + (1 + 3 E^(-3 t)) y[t],
(1 +E^(-3 t)) x[t] + (1 -E^(-3 t) - 3 E^(-2 t)) y[t], (4+E^(-5 t))x[t]+z[t]}

sol = DSolve[system, {x, y, z}, t]
```

Mathematica gives output as an input. Can you give any recommendation?

```
DSolve[x'[t],y'[t],z'[t]} == {(2 - 3 E^(-2 t)) x[t] + (1 + E^(-3 t)) y[t], 
    (1 + E^(-3 t)) x[t] + (1 - E^(-3 t) - 3 E^(-2 t)) y[t], 
    (4 + E^(-5 t)) x[t] + z[t]}, {x, y, z}, t]
```

Comment: Yours code give me: "DSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential or integral equations of the given functions."?

Comment: hi. thank you for reply.i edited the post to become more clear.

Comment: I do not think there is analytical solution to this. Try numerical.

Comment: **Maple** cannot do it, either.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  Can Maple solve for `{x, y}` without `z`, as in  my answer below?

Comment: @bbgodfrey.Oh No,I made a mistake ,`Maple` can solve for `{x,y}` and for `{x,y,z}`.Yes Yours answer is correct.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  Thanks for checking.  Although I do not use Maple, I surmise from comparisons posted on this site that it is better than Mathematica at solving differential equations.

Comment: @bbgodfrey.Yes `Maple` is better for solving  differential equations. https://www.12000.org/my_notes/kamek/mma_12_maple_2019/KEse1.htm#x3-20001

Answer (score 3):

With help, `DSolve` can obtain symbolic solutions for `{x, y}`, after which `z` can be represented in terms of an integral.  It is convenient to start by labeling the three equations,

```
{eqx, eqy, eqz} = Thread[{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} == 
    {(2 - 3 E^(-2 t)) x[t] + (1 + E^(-3 t)) y[t], 
     (1 + E^(-3 t)) x[t] + (1 - E^(-3 t) - 3 E^(-2 t)) y[t], 
     (4 + E^(-5 t)) x[t] + z[t]}];
```

Then, just as in the question,

```
DSolveValue[{eqx, eqy, eqz}, {x, y, z}, t]
```

returns unevaluated.  Now, since `z` appears only in `eqz`, we might try

```
DSolveValue[{eqx, eqy}, {x, y}, t]
```

but it too returns unevaluated.  Nonetheless, eliminating `y` from `{eqx, eqy}` leads to an equation that can be solved for `x`.

```
Solve[{eqx, eqy}, {y[t], y'[t]}] // Flatten // Simplify;
Simplify[D[eqx, t] /. %];
sx = DSolveValue[%, x, t]

(* Function[{t}, E^(1/6 E^(-3 t) (1 + Sqrt[5] + 9 E^t)) (E^t)^(3/2 - Sqrt[5]/2) C[1] + 
   (E^(E^(-3 t)/6 - 1/6 Sqrt[5] E^(-3 t) + (3 E^(-2 t))/2) (E^t)^(3/2 + Sqrt[5]/2) C[2])
   /Sqrt[5]] *)
```

Then, `y` is obtained algebraically by

```
Solve[Simplify[eqx /. x -> sx], y[t]][[1, 1]] // Simplify // Values;
sy = Function[{t}, Evaluate[%]]
(* Function[{t}, -(1/10) E^(1/6 E^(-3 t) (1 - Sqrt[5] + 9 E^t + 6 E^(3 t) t)) 
   (E^t)^(1/2 - Sqrt[5]/2)
   (5 (1 + Sqrt[5]) E^(1/3 Sqrt[5] E^(-3 t)) C[1] + (-5 + Sqrt[5]) (E^t)^Sqrt[5] C[2])] *)
```

To verify the correctness of these solutions, insert them into the original equations.

```
Simplify[{eqx, eqy} /. x -> sx /. y -> sy]
(* {True, True} *)
```

Finally, solve `eqz` for `z`.

```
DSolveValue[eqz /. x -> sx, z[t], t] // Flatten // Simplify;
sz = Function[{t}, Evaluate[%]]
(* Function[{t}, E^t (C[3] + Inactive[Integrate][
   1/5 E^(-(1/6) E^(-3 K[1]) (-1 + Sqrt[5] - 9 E^K[1] + 30 E^(3 K[1]) K[1])) 
   (E^K[1])^(1/2 - Sqrt[5]/2) (1 + 4 E^(5 K[1])) (5 E^(1/3 Sqrt[5] E^(-3 K[1])) C[1] + 
    Sqrt[5] (E^K[1])^Sqrt[5] C[2]), {K[1], 1, t}])] *)
```